# Chainlink Upkeep not show function in verified proxy contract on bsc testnet

Tags: chainlink, bsc

I'm having an upgradable contract that is verified on bsc testnet (0x7e66DC454FCbeC9fb63f0cdBAcB97dc9dB78c817) but when I register upkeep it only shows functions in proxy contract. I'm using time base option. Can someone tell me why. Tks

Comment: It's because this contract uses a Transparent Upgradable Proxy pattern, which means that If any account other than the admin calls the proxy, the call will be forwarded to the implementation, even if that call matches one of the admin functions exposed by the proxy itself. The implementation address should be 0xB67eb608aE35D64970050082a11d5794aa3E59a2

Comment: @Andrej So like you said, it should have functions in the implementation contract right?